# Overlapping in matplotlib.pyplot.annotate

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have already searched in the site but did not find anything specific for my case.
I wrote a code that plots some pairs of points and writes an identifier number for each pair of points.
The problem is that the identification number is too close to the points and I would like to move the numbers a bit to make the plot more readable.
This is the code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from math import exp, log10
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#dataset
dataset1=np.genfromtxt(fname='/path/to/file1.txt')
dataset2=np.genfromtxt(fname='/path/to/file2.txt')    
source=np.genfromtxt(fname='/path/to/file3.txt')
num=np.array(source[:,0])

x1=np.array(dataset1[:,5]) 
y1=np.array(dataset1[:,20])
x2=np.array(dataset2[:,1]) 
y2=np.array(dataset2[:,10])

# error bars
xe1=np.array(dataset1[:,6])
ye1=np.array(dataset1[:,21])    
xe2l=np.array(dataset2[:,2])
xe2u=np.array(dataset2[:,3])
ye2l=np.array(dataset2[:,11])
ye2u=np.array(dataset2[:,12])


plt.errorbar(x1, y1, xerr=xe1, yerr=ye1, fmt='.', color='red', elinewidth=1, capsize=2, label='wavdetect')
plt.errorbar(x2, y2, xerr=[xe2l, xe2u], yerr=[ye2l, ye2u], fmt='.', color='blue', elinewidth=1, capsize=2, label='my_results')

for i,j in enumerate(num):
    plt.annotate(j, xy=(x2[i],y2[i]), ha='left', va='bottom')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title ('title')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

And the plot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add some white space to your annotation?  To do this you need to actually give `annotate` a formatted string rather than just the number.  Then you can just play around with the number of spaces and newlines you want to pad with.

Without your data I've had to make some up.  Hopefully it's close enough.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#  Made up data
x = np.array([ 312, 485, 100, 600, 200])
y = np.array([ .6, .2, .1, 1.2, 1.3 ])
xerr = x.max()/20
yerr = y.max()/10

plt.errorbar(x,y,xerr=xerr,yerr=yerr,fmt='.', color='red', elinewidth=1, capsize=2)

for i,j in enumerate(num):
    # Create a formatted string with three spaces, one newline
    ann = '   {}\n'.format(j)
    plt.annotate(ann, xy=(x[i],y[i]))
```

[image]

Note that if you're running python2, you'll need to format the string like `ann = '   %.1f\n'%(j)`.